# error compiling roboearth

Tags: ros, roboearth, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i'm trying to install roboearth, folowing this instructions : *http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth*

The installation through  *roboearth.rosinstall* goes well.

But when I try to compile it with *rosmake roboearth*,
I get this error message :

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package re_comm written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/gseverac/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120424-152010/re_comm/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< re_comm [FAIL] [ 0.11 seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> eigen [ make ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package re_2dmap_extractor.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package re_comm.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< eigen ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 23 packages with 2 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/gseverac/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20120424-152010
[ rosmake ] WARNING: Rosdep did not detect the following system dependencies as installed: swi_prolog_sgml, swi_prolog_clib, libjson_java, swi_prolog_http, swi_prolog_xpce, swi_prolog_odbc, swi_prolog_semweb, swi_prolog Consider using --rosdep-install option or `rosdep install re_kinect_object_detector re_object_detector_gui ar_bounding_box re_object_recorder re_2dmap_extractor re_ontology re_srvs re_vision re_msgs re_comm`

then when I try *rosdep install re_kinect_object_detector re_object_detector_gui ar_bounding_box re_object_recorder re_2dmap_extractor re_ontology re_srvs re_vision re_msgs re_comm*

I get the error :

ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource mod_probcog

and then I'm stuck ...

Do you have an idea of what i can try or test ?

Thanks,

Gaëtan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32461/error-compiling-roboearth/) by [Gaëtan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1463/ga%C3%ABtan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Bence Magyar](https://answers.ros.org/users/1102/bence-magyar/) on 2012-04-24**:
Please also provide the distribution and Ubuntu version you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's working know

executing :

*apt-get install ros-electric-client-rosjava-jni*

and

*apt-get install libjson-glib-dev*

then specifying the *https_proxy=xxx* in front of the *rosmake roboearth* command

For info and answer i use Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Gaëtan

---

Originally posted by [Gaëtan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1463/ga%C3%ABtan/) with karma: 56 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2